# Why is this aurelia data bound change not rendering in EDGE

Tags: aurelia, microsoft-edge, shadow-dom

This is a strange issue in EDGE where I think the DOM **is** being updated, but the rendered view does not reflect that (until you resize the window). Can anyone tell me why?

gist doesn't work in EDGE for some reason so I've recreated in a project using the Aurelia cli:

https://github.com/AnthonyWard/aurelia-edge-dom-render-issue

### edge-dom-render-issue

To show an issue with the EDGE browser

install the aurelia cli `npm install aurelia-cli -g`

run `npm install` then `au run`

Open EDGE and go to `http://localhost:9000/`

**Select 1**, which represents object `{ id: 1, name: 'This has an optional property', optional: "Hi, I'm optional" }`

Then **select 2** which represents object `{ id: 2, name: "This doesn't have an optional property",  }`

In EDGE you will notice that the **optional field remains**, but in Chrome it does not (the desired behaviour). If you **resize the EDGE window** the optional property dissappears and the result becomes the same as in Chrome. Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0. Microsoft EdgeHTML 14.14393.**

For other tests go back to 1, and then select 2, 3, or 4 etc.

```
this.things = [
    { id: 1, name: 'This has an optional property', optional: "Hi, I'm optional"  },
    { id: 2, name: "This doesn't have an optional property" },
    { id: 3, name: 'This has a null optional property', optional: null  },
    { id: 4, name: 'This has an undefined optional property', optional: undefined  },
    { id: 5, name: 'This has an empty string optional property', optional: ""  },
    { id: 6, name: 'This has a whitespace string optional property', optional: " "  }
];
```

They all exhibit the same behaviour. Why?

- **Library Version:**
  1.1.0
- **Operating System:**
  Windows 10
- **Node Version:**
  7.5.0
- **NPM Version:**
  4.1.2
- **Browser:**
  Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0. 
  Microsoft EdgeHTML 14.14393.

Comment: gist.run doesn't work in Edge b/c the current version of Edge doesn't support Service Workers, unfortunately.